# JDO Query Parsing for field names starting with "new"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, datanucleus

I have a persistent class `NewsClass` with persistent field `newsSource`.

```
// PERSISTENT
class NewsClass {

    // Persistent
    String newsSource;

    // Other persistent fields
}
```

Now to query this entity

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(NewsClass.class);
q.setFilter("newsSource=='http://somerandomurl'");
List<NewsClass> result = (List<NewsClass>) q.execute();
```

It turns out that JDO doesn't look for the `newsSource` field but rather tries an instantiation like `new sSource()`. I also tried things like `q.setFileter("\"newsSource\"=='http://reandomurl'");` as a workaround but didn't work either.

There's about 1GB of data already (on the AppEngine datastore which uses a soft schema) so renaming the field doesn't really look like a good idea.

Please how do I make this query work?

### EDIT

Here's what I got in my logger.

```
CreatorExpression defined with class of sSourceId yet this class is not found
```

Comment: You make various assertions there yet provide no evidence for them. Why not look at the log at DEBUG level and show us what it says for that query?

Comment: What is your progress so far ?

Comment: Question edited, more information added. Thanks.

Comment: You say that your persistent class is `NewsClass`, but your code extract has the class as `NewsDTO`. Can you give the code for your `NewsClass` persistent class? Also, have you tried `q.setFilter("newsSource == \"http://somerandomurl\"");`? (I prefer using parameters for my filters.)

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried changing class names so as not to publicly give out proprietary code that doesn't fully belong to me. And yes, I've several different combinations of ' ' and \" \", all no avail (most of them lead to expression parsing errors).

Comment: (You might want to include a hash tag of the form `#HelpfulPerson` to ensure that he/she/I get a message that you have commented for them to see.) I suggest you study the GAE/J documentation on queries in JDO and then adjust your code accordingly. (I recommend using query parameters in a filter.)

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana I've switched to the AppEngine datastore low-level API since it doesn't have all these drama :)

Comment: @SayoOladeji, thanks for sharing. Too bad JDO didn't help.